# Waiting in the Summer and Onegai Sensei seem to plagiarise each other. Is this normal in anime/manga?

Tags: anime-production, waiting-in-the-summer, please-teacher

*Waiting in the Summer* and *Onegai Sensei* have TONS of things in common:

- Luscious Redhead Alien Main Romantic Interest? **Check**.
- Is she a [Meganekko <sup>(warning: TV Tropes)</sup>](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Meganekko) even though her advanced alien civilization surely can fix the need for glasses? **Check**.
- Mature demeanor indicating a slightly older woman? **Check**.
- Works as a neutral observer on Earth? **Check**.
- Cannot get into a relationship with natives due to alien regulations and job specifications? **Check**.

  [image: Ano Natsu de Matteru Vol 1 cover]
  [image: Onegai Sensei Vol 1 cover]
- Likes to look candidly over the shoulder while holding arms stiff against the back so to enhance the "natural attributes" during the show OP? **CHECK!**

  [image: Women looking over their shoulders]
- Almost kills the MC during the first episode due to crappy piloting re-entry skills? **Check**.
- Saves the life of MC after the crash? **Check**.

  [image: Space vehicle crashing]
- Strange critter that doubles as the spaceship control interface? **Check**.
- Critter has the ability to teleport said alien redhead on demand? **Check**.

  [image: Ano Natsu de Matteru critter (Rinon)]
  [image: Onegai Sensei critter]
- Lolita manipulator that seems to know everything behind the scenes? **Check**.
- Secondary "death flagged" romantic interest that never stands a chance against the aforementioned hot redhead alien? **Check**.
- Redhead is forcefully removed from Earth for breaking alien law? **Check**.
- Japanese countryside (almost rural) setting? **Check**.
- Character design by [Taraku Uon](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1630802/)? **Check**.
- Manga serialized by Media Works? **Check**.

I really felt deja vu all the time.

Is it common to repack almost the same story, setting and characters into another series?

---

I already told how the series are almost a copy of one another, I want to know how common is it to repack the same basic storyline and sell it again.

If the two series are in the same world is stuff for another question: [What proof do we have that Waiting in the Summer and Onegai Sensei (and Twins by proxy) are set in the same Earth?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/26236)

Comment: "I want to know how common is it to repack the same basic storyline and sell it again" - well, this is kind of difficult to answer. What makes two storylines basically the same? Do all the shows that entail basically "high school boy meets mysterious girl, gets superpowers, and fights evil" count as the same storyline? Because you see that all over the place. Or do you want something more along the lines of Ano Natsu / Onegai Sensei? Because I think it should be obvious that this rare, bordering on nonexistent.

Comment: With the way you present the evidences of how the 2 series are so similar, people will immediately ask themselves the question why. You might want to change this question to align with that idea, and ask a different question for your actual question ("Is it common to repack almost the same story, setting and characters into another series?"), citing these 2 series as example, without going into all the details about their similarity.

Answer (score 11):

These two anime are made by the same people. Yousuke Kuroda, story writer of *Onegai Sensee*, collaborated with the character creator of the Onegai franchise, Taraku Uon, to bring us *Ano Natsu de Matteru* <sup>[[1]](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2011-08-28/onegai-franchise-creator-designer-make-ano-natsu-de-matteiru-anime)[[2]](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/news/2012-01-04/crunchyroll-to-stream-ano-natsu-de-matteru-anime)</sup>.

I would say that what you're experiencing is the many [tropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/WaitingInTheSummer?from=Anime.AnoNatsuDeMatteru)<sup>caution!</sup> that are in common between these anime. Since these anime share a creator this is significantly magnified. There are many common tropes and themes that are shared between stories as they are the building blocks of making an interesting plot and storyline.

When watching anime I often can pick up when a show is going to be similar to another show, even early on.  That is because another way to think of these tropes is as a sort of template that the creator can use to layout basic plot elements and then fill in the rest of the storyline with their original ideas.  Depending on how well they are able to add their own twist to this template determines how much of a copy it will feel like. Your question asks if this is common in anime or manga, but this isn't just restricted to anime. These ideas apply to broadcasting and entertainment in general, look at all those generic reality TV shows that are popular among baby boomers. If something is popular, they reuse it.  Then, when someone innovates and creates something people truly love, it too will be copied.

While it may seem like déjà vu in such a closely related example like *Ano Natsu de Matteru* and *Onegai Sensee*, in my experience shows this similar are very rare.  Perhaps, these two shows are the best possible paradigm for your question.

Comment: I take it you've seen Onegai Sensei. I haven't, but I have seen Ano Natsu - and I seem to remember reading that the last episode of Ano Natsu had some references to suggest that Ano Natsu _was_ actually in the same universe as Onegai Sensei. Could you comment on that?

Comment: You're right, I will correct that, it had been a while since I've seen the two and forgot that little reference in episode 12.